# Unable to inherit class from one to other testcase file in selenium - ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium, inheritance

I'm not able to inherit class from one to another testcase file in selenium - ruby environment .

Please check below attached image

[image]

Here I have inherit `launch.rb` in `compare.rb`. But its not working.

Comment: you have to import the file/class using require statement

Comment: Please inline the relevant code and error in the question and remove the image. This makes sure that all the necessary context for future readers will be here, even if the link stops working. Also makes it easier to copy-paste.

Comment: You have to require `launch.rb` in `compare.rb`. Still, please take a look at the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) pages.

Comment: I have tried this using require as well. But using that method mention in compare class is not executing only launch class is executed.